# A simple RcppArmadillo index issue

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm coding with `RcppArmadillo` and got stuck with a very basic question. Suppose I have a vector "v", and I want to take its first 10 elements, like in R: `v[1:10]`. Since `1:10` doesn't work in `RcppArmadillo`, I tried `v.elem(seq_len(10))`, but it didn't work. Any hint?

Comment: Take a look at [the API docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat). Try `v.subvec(1, 10)`.

Comment: The only way I can figure out now is                                            IntegerVector iv = seq_len(10) ;
    uvec idx =  as<uvec>(iv) - 1;
    vec subset = v.elem(idx);
That looks so stupid. If I write v.elem(as<uvec>(seq_len(10)) - 1), it didn't work, maybe I used inappropriate namespace? I code it in Rstudio cpp file...

Comment: To access the first 10 elements of a vector, use `v.head(10)`.  To access the last 10 elements, use `v.tail(10)`. See the part about _contiguous views for vector V_ in the documentation for [submatrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're taking about an `arma::vec`, this should work:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec f(const arma::vec & v, int first, int last) {
    arma::vec out = v.subvec(first, last);
    return out;
}

/*** R
f(11:20, 3, 6)
*/
```

Note that this uses zero-based indexing (`11` is the 0th element of the vector). Coerce to `NumericVector` as desired.

When source'ed into R, the code is compiled, linked, loaded and the embedded example is executed:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/armaEx.cpp")

R> f(11:20, 3, 6)
     [,1]
[1,]   14
[2,]   15
[3,]   16
[4,]   17
R>
```

So it all really is _just one call to `subvec()`.  See the Armadillo documentation for more.

Comment: Do you mind if I replace this fine answer with one using Attributes? Ie keep it your answer but just edit it?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Feel free :)

Comment: Got it! Just one more question, why can't I directly  return v.subvec(first, last);    Is it because  v.subvec() itself is not vec type? BTW, I like your book, @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: @ChongliangLuo - I think that `v.subvec` is an `arma::subview_col`, which is maybe not convertible to SEXP. Not 100% sure, though...

Comment: For the specific case of getting the first 10 elements, it's easier to simply use `v.head(10)`

Comment: @mtall - yes, it is (and note that `head()` was [introduced relatively recently](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#api_additions), so requires `RcppArmadillo` v. 0.4.650.1.0 or later, I believe).

Comment: @mtall true yet somewhat irrelevant as it is not what OP asked about.  This wasn't about convenient shorthand but about _basic (mis)understanding of indexing_.