# Check BIC via RcppArmadillo(Rcpp)

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I want check the BIC usage in statistics. 
My little example, which is saved as **check_bic.cpp**, is presented as follows:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List check_bic(const int N = 10, const int p = 20, const double seed=0){
    arma_rng::set_seed(seed); // for reproducibility
    arma::mat Beta = randu(p,N); //randu/randn:random values(uniform and normal distributions)
    arma::vec Bic = randu(N);
    uvec ii = find(Bic == min(Bic)); // may be just one or several elements
    int id = ii(ii.n_elem); // fetch the last one element
    vec behat = Beta.col(id); // fetch the id column of matrix Beta
    List ret;
    ret["Bic"] = Bic;
    ret["ii"] = ii;
    ret["id"] = id;
    ret["Beta"] = Beta;
    ret["behat"] = behat;
    return ret;
}
```

Then I compile  **check_bic.cpp** in R by

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo);
sourceCpp("check_bic.cpp")
```

and the compilation can pass successfully. 
However, when I ran

```
check_bic(10,20,0)
```

in R, it shows errors as

```
error: Mat::operator(): index out of bounds
Error in check_bic(10, 20, 0) : Mat::operator(): index out of bounds
```

I check the **.cpp** code line by line, and guess the problems probably 
happen at

```
uvec ii = find(Bic == min(Bic)); // may be just one or several elements
int id = ii(ii.n_elem); // fetch the last one element
```

since if `uvec ii` only has one element, then `ii.n_elem` may be NaN or something
else in Rcpp (while it's ok in Matlab), while I dont konw how to 
deal with case. Any help?

Comment: I search solutions on *stack* website and according to  [A simple RcppArmadillo index issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640048/a-simple-rcpparmadillo-index-issue), I change  `int id = ii(ii.n_elem); ` to `int id = ii.tail(1);`,  then still have the errors `cannot convert arma::subview_col<unsigned int> to int in initialization   int id = ii.tail(1); `

Comment: C++ counts from 0. If `ii.n_elem` is non-zero, the last element of `ii` is `ii.n_elem-1`. Or you can use [.back()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#compat_container_fns) instead, like so: `id = ii.back()`

Comment: @mtall is right -- using `back()` will fix your problem. Could be an answer mtall, no?

Comment: Wow, quite helpful answers and save my days! Both `.back()` and  `ii.n_elem-1` work! Tks a lot!@mtall  And also thank you!@duckmayr